# How to display a PyGTK window launched as root, by cron?

Tags: python, cron

I'm using Kubuntu with unattended-upgrades (automatic upgrade), launched by cron, in root.
I have written a script in PyGTK who needs to be displayed on my screen, called in unattended-upgrade by:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'my_script.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.flush()
```

In my script, I've this:

```
import os    
env = os.environ.copy()
env['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'
```

But I've got this error:

> /etc/cron.daily/apt:
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py:57:
>   GtkWarning: could not open display  warnings.warn(str(e),
>   _gtk.Warning) /my_script.py:143: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I will try this:

env = os.environ.copy()
os.environ.setdefault('XAUTHORITY', '/home/guillaume/.Xauthority')
xauth_filename = '/home/guillaume/.Xauthority'
os.environ.setdefault('XAUTHORITY', xauth_filename)
os.environ.setdefault('DISPLAY', ':0.0')
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'my_script.py']

Comment: fixed, I've removed
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
in /etc/anacrontab